# sigaction() sa_flags and POSIX.1-2001 Base Spec

Tags: signals, posix

This is an excerpt from **SIGACTION(2)**:

```
   POSIX.1-1990 specified  only  SA_NOCLDSTOP.   POSIX.1-2001  added  SA_NOCLDSTOP,  SA_NOCLDWAIT,
   SA_NODEFER,  SA_ONSTACK,  SA_RESETHAND, SA_RESTART, and SA_SIGINFO.  Use of these latter values
   in sa_flags may be less portable in applications intended for older UNIX implementations.
```

And from **FEATURE_TEST_MACROS(7)**:

```
    _POSIX_C_SOURCE
           ·  (Since  glibc  2.3.3)  The value 200112L or greater additionally exposes definitions
              corresponding to the POSIX.1-2001 base specification (excluding the XSI  extension).
              This value also causes C95 (since glibc 2.12) and C99 (since glibc 2.10) features to
              be exposed (in other words, the equivalent of defining _ISOC99_SOURCE).
```

But in reality, the flags added in 2001 spec is not exposed when the value `200112L` is used. So, the following code does not compile. I tried glibc and uclibc.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <unistd.h>


static int ret = 1;

void handle_signal (const int s) {
    ret = 0;
}

int main (const int argc, const char **args) {
    struct sigaction sa;

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESETHAND;
    sa.sa_sigaction = handle_signal;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGTERM, &sa, NULL);

    pause();

    return ret;
}
```

What am I missing here? Are the flags not 2001 base spec? Are they an extension? Or is this just a bug in Linux libc implementations?

Comment: At least on glibc, [it seems to be gated by `__USE_XOPEN_EXTENDED`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=bits/sigaction.h;h=afcbd871071dd2d6d30753c76b1ae8d673b92064;hb=78e09591a59fb4cb634cde28089924383151fcfe#l61) (so you may need to `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED` instead)

Comment: @schily "Why `_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L` macro define wouldn't expose `SA_*` flags". Thank you.

Comment: @Ashethehuman you seem to be suffering from `const`ite. As to your problem, good luck finding a POSIX historian who would confirm you whether `SA_RESETHAND` has become standard 20 or 15 years ago. In [susv3](http://www.ing.iac.es/~docs/external/susv3/functions/sigaction.html) aka POSIX-1.2001 `SA_RESTARTHAND` still appears marked as `XSI` (X/Open System Interface). Assuming that that (googled out) page is right.

Comment: @user414777 The SA_ macros are from 1990 which is from before SVr4 has been declared final . The definitions at that time have been disabled in Solaris for a strict POSIX or XOPEN compilation. They are IIRC the SYSVr4 equivalent to the BSD sigvec interface. POSIX.1-2001 was the first POSIX standard that adopted the Single UNIX standard and SUSv2 from 1997 definitely included SA_* already.

Comment: @user414777 Yes, I live in excruciating pain everyday

Comment: I'll just have to compile that code in different Unix OSes, then.

Comment: @Ashethehuman In any Unix, the compiler will complain if you set the `.sa_sigaction` to a pointer of a different type.

Comment: @user414777 I agree. `-Wall` and `-Wextra` are our friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the GNU C library, `SA_RESETHAND` is exposed by [`__USE_XOPEN_EXTENDED` or `__USE_XOPEN2K8`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=bits/sigaction.h;h=afcbd871071dd2d6d30753c76b1ae8d673b92064;hb=78e09591a59fb4cb634cde28089924383151fcfe#l61). [As a result](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html), setting `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to 200112 isn’t sufficient; instead, you need

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
```

(which enables `__USE_XOPEN_EXTENDED`) or

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
```

(which enables `__USE_XOPEN2K8`).

As I understand it, this is POSIX-conformant: before Issue 7, `SA_RESETHAND`, `SA_RESTART`, `SA_SIGINFO`, `SA_NOCLDWAIT`, and `SA_NODEFER` were part of the XSI option. They were moved to Base [in Issue 7 (2008)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html#tag_13_42_11).

[`man 2 sigaction`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) comes from [the Linux man-pages project](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/), not from the GNU C library, so discrepancies do happen.

Comment: Well, technically this is the answer to "Why _POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L macro define wouldn't expose SA_* flags"

Comment: It was my mistake that I rephrased the question. What I really wanted to know was if this is a bug in Linux libc implementations. No offence, but I know how to read C code.

Comment: Sorry, I’ve updated the answer specifically to address whether this is a bug.

Comment: `__USE_XOPEN_EXTENDED` is not mentioned in the POSIX standard. As mentioned already, the observed behavior is a result from the odd way of dealing with POSIX on Linux.

Comment: @StephenKitt You're right. They were. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/signal.h.html. They need to update man pages.

Comment: @schily yes, `__USE_XOPEN_EXTENDED` is an implementation detail. But POSIX itself states that, in Issue 6, `SA_RESETHAND` etc. required `_X_OPEN_SOURCE` to be defined as 600, not just `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`.

Comment: @StephenKitt You seem to forget that `SA_RESETHAND` dates from 1990 and intended to support the historic UNIX signal interface as well and not making it available by default or easily selectable is preventing portability.

Comment: @schily I didn’t write POSIX.